# Woocommerce Checkout Option Choice

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I am currently looking for a way user can choose means of checkout either via coupon code or gateway payment inside checkout page.

For instance, if you land on a checkout page you should see 2 buttons with different options... 
1. For coupon. 
2. For Gateway.

Then select 1 option to proceed your purchase and complete your order

Comment: Please try to reword your question adding some more details, as it's not very understandable and detailed, so it is unclear.

Comment: I have edited the question @LoicTheAztec please check and see if you can still understand it

Comment: Coupons are not made for payment, and can't work as a payment gateway in checkout. What you are asking is a real development. In Stack OverFlow you should provide some related code in your question, that shows that you have already something. Please remember that Stack OverFlow is not a free coding service.